# How to sum readonly field values and dynamically added column values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/bxvthjza/2/)**

I have dynamic rows I just want to sum of dynamically added columns.

Here is my non-working code - I just want to sum readonly field value and dynamically added values

```js
    var ctr = 1;
    var FieldCount = 1;
    $('#fst_row').on('click', '.button-add', function() {
      ctr++;
      var cashacc_code = 'cashacc_code' + ctr;
      var cashacc = 'cashacc' + ctr;
      var cash_narrat = 'cash_narrat' + ctr;
      var cashdeb = 'cashdeb' + ctr;
      var cashcredit = 'cashcredit' + ctr;
      var newTr = '<tr class="jsrow"><td><input type="number" class=' + "joe" + ' id=' + cashacc_code + ' placeholder="NNNN" /></td><td><select class="form-control" id="cashacc" ><option value="">TDS A/C Name1</option><option value="1">Joe</option><option value="2">Joe</option><option value="3">Joe</option></select></td><td><input type="text" class=' + "joe" + ' id=' + cash_narrat + ' placeholder="Enter Here" /></td><td><input type="number" class=' + "joe" + ' id=' + cashdeb + ' ' + FieldCount + ' placeholder="NNNN" /></td><td><input type="number" class=' + "joe" + ' id=' + cashcredit + ' /></td><td style="width: 4%"><img src="./img/plus.svg" class="insrt-icon button-add"><img src="./img/delete.svg" class="dlt-icon"></td></tr>';
      $('#cashTable').append(newTr);

      $(document).on('click', '.dlt-icon', function() {
        $(this).parents('tr.jsrow').first().remove();
      });
    });


    /* second row  */

    var ctr = 1;
    var FieldCount = 1;
    $('#sndRow').on('click', '.button-add', function() {
      ctr++;
      var rowNum = 'rowNum' + ctr;
      var cashacc_nme = 'cashacc_nme' + ctr;
      var acc_narrat = 'acc_narrat' + ctr;
      var accdeb = 'accdeb' + ctr;
      var accCredit = 'accCredit' + ctr;
      var newTr = '<tr class="jsrow"><td><input type="number" class=' + "joe" + ' id=' + rowNum + ' placeholder="NNNN" /></td><td><select class="form-control" id="cashacc_nme" ><option value="">Account Name 1</option><option value="1">Plumz</option><option value="2">Plumz</option><option value="3">Plumz</option></select></td><td><input type="text" class=' + "joe" + ' id=' + acc_narrat + ' placeholder="Enter Here" /></td><td><input type="number" class=' + "joe debClass" + ' id=' + accdeb + ' ' + FieldCount + ' placeholder="NNNN" /></td><td><input type="number" class=' + "joe" + ' id=' + accCredit + ' /></td><td style="width: 4%"><img src="./img/plus.svg" class="insrt-icon button-add"><img src="./img/delete.svg" class="dlt-icon"></td></tr>';
      $('#cashTable').append(newTr);

      $(document).on('click', '.dlt-icon', function() {
        $(this).parents('tr.jsrow').first().remove();
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So what do you want to count? And where is your code that count something?

Comment: I can attached my Fiddle bro https://jsfiddle.net/bxvthjza/2/   I just want to sum of dynamically adding ** Debit columns** only..

Comment: So where is your "Sum" method? You should try to do it first and if there is some problems then ask for help. It is not coding service.